# Speed up 400 GB Redis Restore

Tags: redis

I have a 400 GB `backup.rdb` backup file which I need to restore to a fresh redis instance.

The problem is, when I last attempted to restore it, it took 2+ days to load the data from the backup file into memory.  I was running one of the fastest ec2 instances, the `x1.32xlarge` instance size with ~2 TB of ram and 128 cores.

Even with this kind of server power, I was still only getting a few mb of transfer a second and the process took too long.  I was wondering if there was a way I could speed up the restoration process?

Are there hard limits on the Ubuntu machine or Redis configuration which I could remove/increase to make this process faster?  Would using a redis cluster speed up the time it takes to restore the backup?

Open to ideas, thanks!

Comment: if I may ask, wondering what is your use case, and if you have considered using other alternatives probably like something like dynamodb? (how redis behaves at does magnitudes, still returning values fast (< 1 sec)

Comment: Our use case is very specific at the moment, I don't know if I get get into it.  However, this dynamoDB looks like a way better fit for what we're trying to do compared to Redis.  I'll look into it more with my team, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Looks like a limitation of AWS, not Redis. I restored 200gb dumps within 15 seconds on my local machine. Except maybe you have some complex structures? Anyway, test it on local machine. Redis RDB restore is very efficient.

Comment: How did you exactly restore it? Placed `rdb` file in the Redis working directory and started the server?

Comment: yes it's in the working directory and I've been declaring that DB file explicitly when launching it